# Laravel get data in through relation

Tags: php, laravel

I use this `hasOneThrough` to get `user` through `post` to display result inf `file`:

**Controller**

```
File::where('agent_id', $user->id)
                ->with(['user' => function ($q) {
                    $q->select('name','phone');
                }])->get(['post_id', 'status']);
```

**Model**

```
// __________________________ related__|__through_|_1key_|_2key_|_lkey_|_seclkey

return $this->hasOneThrough('App\User', 'App\Post', 'id', 'id', 'post_id', 'user_id');

// ___________________________________________^ > want to get `hash` from `post`
```

This work good, but now I need one item from `post`  called `hash` in this result, is it possible to get any data from `through` (Post table). Already able to get any data from `file` and `user` but how can I get data from `through` *(Post table)* ?

I don't know how can do this, so I searched and nothing found, so I couldn't try anything.

Comment: there is no 'through' table?...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia `App\Post` is `through` here. there is `posts` table.

Comment: and you want the Post associated to that File?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes, file has `post_id` and as you see, already I able to get `user through `post_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `hasOne` in your model:

```
public function post(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post', 'id', 'post_id');
}
```

And in your controller you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) but I noticed you get `null`, in order for this to work, you also have to select the id:

```
$files = File::where('agent_id', $user->id)->with('user:phone,name', 'post:id,hash')->get(['post_id', 'status']);
```

Comment: Oh great, I thought it was an issue in my project, but why? is it laravel bug or there is reason ? although the prev answer has good point and gave me a solution but your answer is perfecter than prev.

Answer (score 1):

If your `File` table has a `post_id`, and between `posts` and `files` table  there is a One to Many relation, just declare a new relation:

```php
public function post(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

Also keep in mind that if inside a `with` you want to select only specific fields, you can just do `->with('user:phone,name')`

Comment: Oh, last tip is great, thank you for this. and also your solution work fine, great answer!

Comment: In `model` should get like this-> `->with('user:phone,name', 'post:hash')`  ? if yes I got `"post": null`

Comment: can't see why not, but can't find any example, and i've no test cases to test it..

Comment: Logically it should work, but it work only like this `->with('user:phone,name', 'post')` but it return all data from post, but I want only `hash`

Comment: try with `->with([ 'user:phone,name', 'post:hash' ]) `

Comment: Same. weird, I also tried, `return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'post_id', 'id')->select(array('hash'));` still return `null`, probably there is something in my project, forget it :) thanks again